# How can I make PowerShell CMake module display full error message and not trim it?

Tags: powershell, cmake

When running CMake using powershell script that fails, it always cuts the error messages and suffixes (or prefix) them with `...` either showing only first few words, or last few words, never full error.

For example:

```
Checking paths...     OK
Looking for MSBuild...    OK
Looking for Qt5...    OK
Looking for OpenSSL...    OK
Looking for nsis...    OK
Looking for git...    OK
Looking for cmake...    OK
Configuring the project...
Running cmake
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
cmake : CMake Error at extensions/extension-mass-delete/CMakeLists.txt:26 (find_package):
At C:\Users\Petr Bena\Documents\huggle3-qt-lx\windows\release.ps1:172 char:5
+     cmake ..\..\src\ -G "$cmake_generator" -DWEB_ENGINE=true -DPYTHON ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CMake Error at ...(find_package)::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

This kind of error doesn't help at all identifying what is wrong, because it's too generic. How can I unfold it so that I see full error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `try{ } catch { }` block to catch the exception and then access error properties. Here's a custom error writing function I wrote:

```
Function Write-CustomError()
{
<#
.Synopsis
   Displays error information to the console
.DESCRIPTION
    Writes property information from the current [ErrorRecord] object
    in the pipeline to the console
.EXAMPLE
   Write-CustomError -UserMessage "Exception occurred at memory location $x" -ErrorObject $_
.EXAMPLE
   Write-CustomError -UserMessage "Exception occurred at memory location $x" -ErrorObject $_ -FullDetail
.INPUTS
   $Error[0]
.OUTPUTS
   [String]
.COMPONENT
   adminkitMiscTools   
.FUNCTIONALITY
   General Utility
#>
    [cmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
        [String]$UserMessage,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [Object]$ErrorObject,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [Switch]$FullDetail
    )

    BEGIN
    {}
    PROCESS
    {
        if($UserMessage) {
             Write-Host "`nERROR: $UserMessage" -ForegroundColor Red
        }

        if($FullDetail)
        {
            $ErrorData = $ErrorData + [PSCustomObject]@{AccountUsed=$ENV:USERNAME;
                                            ExceptionMessage=$ErrorObject.ToString();
                                            CategoryInfo=$ErrorObject.CategoryInfo;
                                            ExceptionType=$ErrorObject.Exception.GetType();
                                            ErrorDetails=$ErrorObject.ErrorDetails;
                                            FullyQualifiedErrorId=$ErrorObject.FullyQualifiedErrorId;
                                            InvocationInfo=$ErrorObject.InvocationInfo;
                                            PipelineIterationInfo=$ErrorObject.PipelineIterationInfo;
                                            ScriptStackTrace=$ErrorObject.ScriptStackTrace
                                            TargetObject=$ErrorObject.TargetObject;
                                            }
        }
        return $ErrorData
    }
    END
    {}
}
```

In your script:

```
try { 
      # your cmake command here 
 }
catch {
     Write-CustomError -UserMessage 'There was an error' -ErrorObject $_ -FullDetail
}
```

That will give you much more detail about the error and shouldn't clip messages